# Issue in setting card type in CitrusPay gateway swift ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payment-gateway, citrus-pay

I am trying to set card type in **CitrusPay** in **Swift**

I need help converting following **Objective-C** line to **Swift**

```
CTSElectronicCardUpdate *debitCard = [[CTSElectronicCardUpdate alloc] initDebitCard];
```

This is what compiler suggested me:

```
let debitCard: CTSElectronicCardUpdate = CTSElectronicCardUpdate.init(debitCard: ())
```

so the **debitCard** is expecting function type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
 let debitCard = CTSElectronicCardUpdate(debitCard: ())
 debitCard.number = cardNumber.
 debitCard.expiryDate = formatted; //only mm/yyyy format
 debitCard.scheme = CTSUtility.fetchCardSchemeForCardNumber(number Here)
 debitCard.ownerName = userName.value; // no special characters here
 debitCard.cvv = cvv.value;
```

Comment: for testing purpose, I am giving dummy static values for 'paymentInfo' object of CTSPaymentDetailUpdate. So can you tell me what values are expected for the properties 'defaultOption' and 'paymentOptions' of 'paymentInfo' object?

Comment: @Nilesh - Did you manage to integrate citrus pay successfully?

Comment: @shivamkaushik No, I couldn't complete it yet. I'm going to try it again.

Comment: If you do manage to complete it, Would you like to share the code?

Comment: Can you please share the code for credit card payment